# Independent ActiveRecord query inside ActiveRecord::Relation context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, activerecord-relation

There is some ruby on rails code

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.all_users_count
    User.all
  end
end
```

`User.all_users_count` 
returns, for example, **100**

`User.limit(5).all_users_count` 
Now it return **5** because of ActiveRecord::Relation context, in despite of i wroute name of class `User.all` instead simple `all`
(.to_sql show that query always contains `limit` or `where id` or other things in other cases)

So, how can i make context-independent AR queries inside model methods? like `User.all` and others?

Thank you!

Ps. Or maybe my code has an error or something like this, and in fact `User.all` inside any methods and context always must returns correct rows count of this model table

Answer (score 1):

This is very weird and unexpected (unfortunately I can't confirm that, because my computer crashed, and have no rails projects at hand).

I would expect

```
User.all
```

to create a new scope (or as you call it - context)

Try working around this with

```
User.unscoped.all
```

Edit:

I tried it out on my project and on clean rails repo, and the results are consistent.

And after thinking a bit - this is maybe not even an issue - I think your approach could be faulty.

In what scenario would you chain `User.limit(2).all_users_count` ?? I can't think of any. Because either you need all users count, and you call `User.all_usert_count` (or just `User.count`)

... or you need something else and you call `User.limit(2).where(...)` - there's no point in calling `all_users_count` in that chain, is it?

And, when you think of it, it makes sense. Imagine you had some different method like `count_retired`, what would you expect from such call:

`User.limit(2).count_retired` ?

The number of retired users not bigger than 2, or the number of all retired users in the system? I would expect the former.

So I think one of two possibilities here:

- either you implemented it wrong and should do it in a different way (as described above in the edit section)
- or you have some more complex issue, but you boiled your examples down to a point where they don't make much sense anymore (please follow up with another question if you please, and please, ping me in the comment with a link if you do, because it sounds interesting)

Comment: **Yes, it works, thanx!** I search "context" and "scope" and other thing and can not find anything about my situation. I suspected that there is a similar method, but is difficult to formulate this problem for google it. Ps. Yes, i agree, it is unexpected behavior, but it is.. at least in my case

Comment: UPD. `unscoped` work well in some simple cases, but when query is bigger and many methods applies on model from other gems (like closure tree) - it is still some additional condition to summary sql query, depend from start Relation context... strange.. ok, thank you very match!

Comment: This is weird and confusing, I'll definitely investigate this when I have some rails project to work on.

Comment: Thank you. So, as a temporary solution for all cases, for now, i create a "mirrow" AR class, based on same table with same config as first one - `User::Mirrow` for example, and if some independent query needs inside of ActiveRecord::Relation scope of User model - i use it mirrow class. Very strage solution, but what else can i do)

Comment: @dmitryck Ok. I managed to do some tests, and I updated my answer - you may be interested.

Comment: yes, thanx, I will read thoughtfully your updated answer tomorrow, and reply to it